# Where should i put keys given by facebook in FBConnect

Tags: iphone, ios, fbconnect

I want to use facebook api in my future iphone project..

I have got App id...App Secret...and api key from the facebook..

Now I want to use it in my FBConnect..

Where should I use this details in the fbConnect?

Answer (score 0):

Use the appID to create the facebook object

> _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];

decide what permissions you want to get

> _permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                         @"read_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];

and then login using

> [_facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];

also dont forget to add the URL fb[appID] to the URL Types key in the info.plist file.